# Access Prometheus default Go metrics from within the code

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics

I have exposed the default and some custom metrics from my Go application.
I can view the metrics in browser as :

```
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes Number of bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_alloc_bytes ***********
```

I want to be able to access these metrics, query them maybe, from within my application code.
I have been looking into client_golang package by prometheus and the prometheus HTTP API but could not find my way around.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: When you say you used the HTTP API, did you query the client (i.e. `localhost`, or the Prometheus server that collects the metrics? You will need to call the API on the server. If you don't want to make an external call, you could install the server locally, have it scrape from localhost and call the API on the locally hosted server. Or just call the endpoint in your code and parse for `go_memstats_alloc_bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access memory information about your running application from within that application, consider referencing [runtime.ReadMemStats](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats).

```golang
var m runtime.MemStats
runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)

// reference m.HeapAlloc or m.TotalAlloc, etc.
```

Note that the current implementation "stops the world" so may be too expensive for an inner loop.